# NSUnknownKeyException: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm pretty new to coding with Swift and I'm trying to populate a UITableView that's inside of a UIViewController with data, but when I navigate to the screen with the UITableView, the app crashes with the following error:

```
2016-12-08 14:22:47.265712 Evil Quest[300:18048] Unknown class QuestCell in Interface 
Builder file.
2016-12-08 14:22:47.270248 Evil Quest[300:18048] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x101847600> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 
lblQuestName.'
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm not sure which part of my code I should post here, so if there's a part of code you need to solve this problem you can tell me and I'll add it to the question.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

cellForRowAt Function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:QuestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! QuestCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.lblQuestName.text = quests[row].name

    return cell
}
```

QuestCell class code:

```
import UIKit

class QuestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblQuestName: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code .

Comment: The issue is related to your cell. Add related code to your question. QuestCell class as well.

Comment: @SagarSnehi, this function?

Comment: @AnniS, should I post the QuestCell class maybe?

Comment: you connected each outlets properly into QuestCell? can you post questcell class also

Comment: @SagarSnehi QuestCell has an outlet lblQuestName -> LbL Quest Name and lblQuestName has an outlet lblQuestName -> QuestCell

Comment: Did you name the cell class in your storyboard QuestCell?

Comment: If you have created a cell in a separate XIB you have to register it with the table view before using it.

Comment: @Steve do you mean the identifier for the TableView Cell, if so yes that's named QuestCell

Comment: Yes, please. Added QuestCell class code as well.

Comment: @JPetric I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Make sure you set tableCell class to QuestCell and IBOutlet is connected.

Comment: Essentially there are two ways (that I know of using IB / Storyboards) to add a cell to the tableview.  One if in storyboards if the tableview has the cell inside of it.  If the XIB file however is just a cell class you need to make sure you register it to the tableView using registerClass method in code.

Comment: Somewhere before tableView is loaded you should call tableView.registerClass or tableView.registerNib methods

Comment: I now have 
        self.tableQuests.register(QuestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuestCell") in the viewDidLoad, do you mean it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to register the class. Try this in the viewDidLoad method of the TableViewController class.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(QuestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuestCell")
```

Also you should check weak variables if they exist. 
Put a breakpoint on this line of your code:

```
cell.lblQuestName.text = quests[row].name
```

Comment: It seems like cell.lblQuestName was nil, I now get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I have replaced cell.lblQuestName.text with cell.textLabel?.text and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to storyboard where you have set the `lblQuestName` label. Check if that label has two or more outlets set to it.

It should only be connected with one outlet. This error is thrown if a view is not connected correctly with an outlet.

Comment: It has one outlet, it's connected to QuestCell